# Are there technical benefits using "param(<params here))" inside a function over "function myfunc(<param here>)"?

Tags: powershell

Why are there two different formatting possible for parameters input? Are there any benefits other than personal taste to this?

For example, i'm using this because that's what I first seen reading documentation about Powershell

```
function MyAwesomeFunction
  (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$Whatever)]
    [string]
    $MyAwesomeVariable = MyAwesomeDefaultValue
  )
  {MyAwesome stuff to do}
```

But there's case when looking at user made examples where the parameters are made that way

```
function MyAwesomeFunction 
  {
    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$Whatever)]
    [string]
    $MyAwesomeVariable = MyAwesomeDefaultValue
    )
  MyAwesome stuff to do
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just writing a plain old function, PowerShell doesn't care which style you use; it should work just as well either way. However, a lot of people use `Param()` for consistency, as it is required in certain situations. Most notably, the `CmdletBinding()` attribute requires the use of `Param()` (even if your function doesn't have any parameters).

Comment: Also, Param() statements are required for scripts and scriptblocks with parameters.